# How to copy id_dsa.pub

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, scp

I am trying to create a backup server for hundreds (500+) of cloud servers that all use iptables which limit ssh connections to our companies IP's only.

All the backups would go to one central cloud "server", the hosts are located in different regions or data centers and running `scp` or `ssh_copy_id` or similar by logging into each one would be a tedious nightmare.

Can I export the key and use it in an "install type script" from a local server to all the servers that would then copy the ssh id for passwordless login and install the cron + script for the automated backups?

Answer (score 1):

I would use puppet, perfect to add files, keys or settings to multiple machines. https://puppet.com/solutions/cloud-management

Answer (score 0):

parallel-scp and parallel-ssh commands from pssh package may also be a simpler solution. You simply keep host ip's in a file to pass as host parameters. The first time parallel-scp will copy the public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in each server and in subsequent runs, you can access the servers through parallel-ssh.

Comment: I have a script that loops scp with a file that contains all of the ip's and root passwords for other purposes like pusing file updates that is not the issue, though pssh is an interesting idea in general, the question is if I copy the ssh key folder to a local server as a file not with the purpose of installing the key but in order to distribute or "copy" the file to other hosts for them to use as the ssh key will it work. 
meaning if i zip /root/.shh/id_dsa.pub or add the key string to a script which creates the key file would that work. 
something like `cat <<EOF 
keystringEOF`

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to go is a script with sshpass and a limited user as a stopgap solution, while we evaluate an "auto deployment" solution. Script is below
Thanks and Happy holidays

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
ServerIP=`ifconfig | grep -A1 "Link encap:Ethernet" | grep -v "Link encap:Ethernet" | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d" " -f1 | egrep '([1-2]?[0-9]{0,2}\.){3,3}[1-2]?[0-9]{0,2}'`
echo "ServerIP is:$ServerIP" > /dev/null

if ! rpm -qa | grep -qw sshpass; then

yum -y install sshpass rsync

elif [ ! -d "/tmp/backup" ] ; then

mkdir -p /tmp/backup && chmod -R 777 /tmp/backup

else

cp -u /etc/sysconfig/iptables /tmp/backup
cp -Ru /var/..../custom/ /tmp/backup
cp -Ru /var/..../somestuff/ /tmp/backup
mysql -uroot -pmysqlpassword < /root/backup.sql

fi

zip -r /tmp/backup/`hostname`_"$ServerIP"_"$now"_Backup.zip /tmp/backup/
rsync -avzh -e "sshpass -p verylongpassword ssh" /tmp/backup/*Backup.zip user@ServerIP:/backups/
rm /tmp/backup/*
```